# How to speed up flutter firestore query?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the below code which is creating a list of updated records. However it is very slow. Please could you help me with the following questions?

1. it is using streambuilder - I don't need the screen to keep updating, should I be using futurebuilder or something else?
2. the database table has 500 columns (sorry it's a legacy problem!) but I am only using 2 columns (name, dlastupd) plus the document id. Can I specify this somewhere to speed up the query?
3. after retrieving the data I sort by dlastupd (timestamp of last update) - should this not be done on the server side somehow? Should I also somehow index the field?
4. am I using listview correctly so that it only loads data that is needed to fill the screen?

   ```
   void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

     runApp(Home());
   }

   class Home extends StatelessWidget {

     // const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Flutter Demo',
         theme: ThemeData(
           primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
         ),

         routes: {
           '/': (context) => ItemList(),
           '/factfile': (context) => ItemDetails(),
         },
       );
     }
   }

   class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {
     ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
       _stream = _reference.snapshots();
     }

     CollectionReference _reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('table_name');

     late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream;

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('Item List'),
         ),

         body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
           stream: _stream,
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             //Check error
             if (snapshot.hasError) {
               return Center(child: Text('Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}'));
             }

             //Check if data arrived
             if (snapshot.hasData) {
               //get the data
               QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
               List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.docs;

               //Convert the documents to Maps
               List<Map> items = documents.map((e) =>
               {
                 'name': e['name'],
                 'dlastupd': e['dlastupd'],
                 'dlastupd date': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e['dlastupd'] * 1000),
                 'id': e.id,
               }).toList();

               // sort in descending date order
               items.sort((a, b) => b["dlastupd"].compareTo(a["dlastupd"]));

               //Display the list
               return ListView.builder(

                   itemCount: items.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     //Get the item at this index
                     Map thisItem = items[index];
                     //Return the widget for the list items
                     return ListTile(

                       title: Text(formatDate(thisItem['dlastupd date'], [dd, '', M]) + " - " + thisItem['name']),
                       onTap: () {
                         Navigator.pushNamed(
                           context,
                           '/factfile',
                           arguments: {
                             'id': thisItem['id'],
                           },
                         );
                       },
                     );
                   });
             }

             //Show loader
             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
           },
         ), //Display a list // Add a FutureBuilder
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: "after retrieving the data I sort by dlastupd (timestamp of last update) - should this not be done on the server side somehow?" Did you see the documentation on ordering data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?

Comment: "the database table has 500 columns (sorry it's a legacy problem!) but I am only using 2 columns (name, dlastupd) plus the document id. Can I specify this somewhere to speed up the query?" Nope. Firestore client-side SDKs always retrieve completely documents. If you want a subset of the data in the client, create additional documents in a different collection with just those fields.

Comment: "it is using streambuilder - I don't need the screen to keep updating, should I be using futurebuilder or something else?" If you want a one-time read, use `get()` and a `FutureBuilder` indeed. Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I tried to answer your questions in comments here. Going forward, please limit yourself to a single question per post. Even if you have multiple questions around the same use-case, posting individual questions is the only way we can continue to build a re-usable knowledge base here.